# SQL Statement Insert field in a column for each change in two other columns field

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, I have a table that I created from an even larger table using this statement in SQL

```
sSql = "SELECT InputID, EstimateLogNumber INTO [EstimateTable] FROM [dbo_tblInput]"
```

I have added a new column into [EstimateTable] called [Options] which should sequentially insert a field value of 'Option A, Option, B, Option C,..etc' for each [InputID] where [EstimateLogNumber] is different. The [InputID] is ordered chronologically though I wouldn't mind descending it to be safe. I am pretty clueless on how to go abotu this and whether or not this is even possible with SQL! But I would love to learn!

```
InputID EstimateLogNumber Options
-----------------------------------------------------------
220     0008305           Option A (This is what I want for every change in Input ID)
221     0009505 
222     0008505
223     0008505
224     0008505
```

Thanks!
Kurt

Comment: Some raw data to work with would be very helpfull!

Comment: So in your example, you want InputID 221 to show Option B and Ids 222, 223 and 224 to show Option C? Or 221 to show Option A, 222 to show Option A 223 to show Option B and 224 to show Option C?

Comment: Your sample data does not align well with your question. From your question I am expecting to see multiple identical `InputIDs` and different `EstimateLogNumbers`.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/703d9/4  (only in access, and with the capability to cope beyond 26 options)?

Comment: Hello OverMind, I see what you mean, I don't believe I interpreted the input ID's relationship to the EstimateLogNumbers properly! I'll investigate and see if I can clarify my question, thank you all for your help